# Can I disable the Macbook's display when the Macbook is hooked up to a big monitor?

Tags: mac, macbook, display, external-display

That's because I don't want to move the windows one by one to the big display, or accidentally move the mouse cursor over to the Macbook's display and not know where it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the MacBook. If a mouse and keyboard are connected, you can wake it up and only use the external display.

Comment: Bonus Info: Some have a problem with heat buildup, others don't want to use external mouse and keyboard, but there is no other way than this.

Comment: wow, the only way is by something physical, not by software!

Comment: @DanielBeck if closing the macbook works there is a switch, so something that adapts the boot/bios sector could easily modify this and fake the switch. You don't have to never install a different bios.